# ^ does not indicate the start of line in python

Tags: python

I have a file `starts_X` as follows :

```
X-hello
X-hello I am j
nX-h
X-
X-hi
```

I try to extract lines that starts with X. So I ran

```
import re
fhandle=open("starts_X")
for line in fhandle:
  if re.search("^X.*",line):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

and got

```
X-hello
X-hello I am j
X-
X-hi
```

However, when I run it without `.` like this :

```
import re
fhandle=open("starts_X")
for line in fhandle:
  if re.search("^X*",line):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

it returns

```
X-hello
X-hello I am j
nX-h
X-
X-hi
```

I learned that `.` matches any character. I thought `"^X.*"` means 'start with X followed by any one or more character' and "^X*" means 'start with X followed by zero or more character'.
What is wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: `X*` means "zero or more Xs". So it can match zero Xs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` means zero or more of a symbol, so when you put it after X you mean the line starts with zero or more occurrences of X which is true for all of your lines.

Comment: It could be better phrased as: "you mean the line **starts** with **zero or more occurrences of X** which is true for all of your lines."

Comment: Maybe also explain that if he wants to match 1 or more he can use `+`.

Comment: Hi, thank you I understood. I have several more questions. 1) So the meaning of regular expressions . and * are different in python that bash shell scripts? 2. Could you verify if I am right? . means any ONE character, and * means zero or more of a symbol preceding right before it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, they are different see https://regex101.com/ for understanding python regex behavior.